# Can I use google drive push notifications on Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I've read article about Google drive push notifications https://developers.google.com/drive/push
And I whould like to use them in my android project. Is it possibe?
If yes can anyone give me idea how.
Thanks.

Comment: not directly. as you can see, the notifications will be sent to a webhook, which is a url you give when registering for the notifications. (you could make a gateway using a server that would transfer the notification to the mobile, though)

Comment: Thanks. Nice idea.
But I whould like to stay away from server for now.
But that whould definitely work

Comment: that would probably not be much more than a few dozen lines in any kind of language, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're currently only pushing notifications to Web hooks, but supporting push notifications on the mobile platforms is in our scope for future releases.

Comment: I know you are working on drive-sdk, can you please tell us about approximate dates of those future releases.

Comment: No date we can give at the moment, Zed.